# get-content not returning full line, if only one line in .txt

Tags: powershell, installation

I have a script to install additional files to an installed program, where many versions of that program can exist.  The installer works brilliantly if there are multiple installs (my pc had 22) but the prompt fails to write a choose location prompt correctly if there's only one.

```
$count = 1
foreach($line in (gc $scriptPath\ExoInst.txt)) 
{
    if($line -match $regex)
    {
        Write-Host $count":"(gc $scriptPath\ExoInst.txt)[$count-1]
        $count++
    }
}
```

This is the failing code,  it simply writes 1:C  to prompt, even while ExoInst.txt has a full install location in it.

A simple `gc` to the `.txt` gets the full text.

Screenshot added. [Code Fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VglEc.png)

Not sure if this is a peculiar behavior with ":" or what.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is variable `$scriptPath` defined? Do you mean `$PSScriptRoot` perhaps? Is `$regex` defined somewhere, can we see that? Can you show us part of the `ExoInst.txt` file?

Comment: Try ```"$count`:$((gc $scriptPath\ExoInst.txt)[$count-1])"```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that for text files that contain only a single line of text, `Get-Content` returns a `String`, and not an array of `String[]`. You can see this with this example:

```
PS C:\> $SingleLine = Get-Content .\SingleLineOfText.txt
PS C:\> $SingleLine
OnlyOneLine
PS C:\> $SingleLine[0]
O
PS C:\> $SingleLine.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object

PS C:\> $MultiLine = Get-Content .\MultipleLinesOfText.txt
PS C:\> $MultiLine
OneLine
TwoLine
ThreeLine
PS C:\> $MultiLine[0]
OneLine
PS C:\> $MultiLine.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

So what is happening is with only a single line of text, returning a `String` object the statement `(gc..)[0]` only returns the first *character* in the string, and not the "expected" first line.

The solution is to make sure that `Get-Content` returns an array. We can do this by wrapping it in the [Array Sub Expression Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7#the-array-sub-expression-operator) i.e. `@( ... )` like so:

```
PS C:\> $SingleLine = @(Get-Content .\SingleLineOfText.txt)
PS C:\> $SingleLine
OnlyOneLine
PS C:\> $SingleLine[0]
OnlyOneLine
PS C:\> $SingleLine.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

So your code becomes (with minor formatting for the output):

```
$count = 1
foreach($line in @(gc $scriptPath\ExoInst.txt)) 
{
    if($line -match $regex)
    {
        Write-Host $count":$(@(gc $scriptPath\ExoInst.txt)[$count-1])"
        $count++
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:

Or, what I would do is to read the file first, then use your `$line` variable... *because it contains the line you are working on* ;-), for cleaner code:

```
$count = 1
$ExoInst = @(gc $scriptPath\ExoInst.txt)
foreach($line in $ExoInst) 
{
    if($line -match $regex)
    {
        Write-Host $count":"$line
        $count++
    }
}
```